# How to Get Each time spending time on particualar location and employee in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Here we are getting automatic db insert when user enter rooms and leaves. The following data is inserted table

```
    id empid location   CreatedDate
    1   1   Block 1     2023-06-01 08:31:16
    2   2   Block 1     2023-06-01 08:31:16
    3   3   Block 1     2023-06-01 08:31:16
    4   4   Block 2     2023-06-01 08:31:16
    5   1   Block 1     2023-06-01 08:51:25
    6   1   Block 1     2023-06-01 09:15:02
    7   2   Block 1     2023-06-01 09:15:15
    8   2   Block 2     2023-06-01 09:20:12
    9   1   Block 1     2023-06-01 09:31:22
   10   1   Block 2     2023-06-01 09:35:22
   11   3   Block 1     2023-06-01 09:37:05
   12   1   Block 2     2023-06-01 09:40:08
```

And i want to show details in report like below

```
      Empid     location    Date        arrived     left        total_spend(seconds)
       1        Block1      2023-06-01  08:31:16    08:51:25    1209
       1        Block1      2023-06-01  09:15:02    09:31:22    980
       1        Block2      2023-06-01  06:35:22    09:40:08    284
       2        Block1      2023-06-01  08:31:16    09:15:15    2639
       2        Block2      2023-06-01  09:20:12    -            -
```

Please help me to how write a query in mysql

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.x, you could use the `row_number` function to aggregate your data as the following:

```
with t as
(
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by empid, location, date_format(CreatedDate, '%Y-%m-%d') order by CreatedDate) rn
  from tbl
)
select empid, location,
       date_format(CreatedDate, '%Y-%m-%d') "Date",
       date_format(min(CreatedDate), '%H:%i:%s') arrived,
       if(min(CreatedDate) = max(CreatedDate), '-', date_format(max(CreatedDate), '%H:%i:%s')) "left",
       timestampdiff(second, min(CreatedDate), max(CreatedDate)) total_spend
from t
group by empid, location, date_format(CreatedDate, '%Y-%m-%d'),
         ((rn+1) div 2)
order by empid, location, min(CreatedDate)
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/DJRuXOlM)

For older versions of MySql 5.x, we can simulate the row_number functionality as the following:

```
set @rn =0;
set @eid = null;
set @loc = null;
set @dtc = null;

select empid, location,
       date_format(CreatedDate, '%Y-%m-%d') "Date",
       date_format(min(CreatedDate), '%H:%i:%s') arrived,
       if(min(CreatedDate) = max(CreatedDate), '-', date_format(max(CreatedDate), '%H:%i:%s')) "left",
       timestampdiff(second, min(CreatedDate), max(CreatedDate)) total_spend
from
(
  select *,
    if(empid <> @eid or location <> @loc or date_format(CreatedDate, '%Y-%m-%d') <> @dtc, 
       @rn := 1, @rn:= @rn + 1) rn,
    @eid := empid,
    @loc := location,
    @dtc := date_format(CreatedDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
  from tbl
  order by empid, location, CreatedDate
) t
group by empid, location, date_format(CreatedDate, '%Y-%m-%d'),
         ((rn+1) div 2)
order by empid, location, min(CreatedDate)
```

This query aggregates the data on a daily basis, if you want to keep going with next days you may remove `or date_format(CreatedDate, '%Y-%m-%d'` from the if statement in the second query.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/JxXxESlu)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but im using mysql 5.5 would u help me

Comment: You are welcome, see the updated answer, I included another query that works on mysql 5.5